# OpenMP within functions

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a loop with 2-3 functions that get called often.
Assume something like so:

```
while(keepRunning())
{
  doLongOne();
  doLongTwo();
  doLongThree();
}
```

while doLong# is essentially:

```
for(it=collection.begin(); it!=collection.end(); it++)
{
  (*it).doLong();
}
```

What I would like to do, is have a `#pragma omp parallel sections` for the loop (a section per function) and a `#pragma omp parallel for` for the loops in each function.
However, I'm not sure if that would work well, considering OMP doesn't properly support multiple `parallel` pragmas.
Considering this, what would be the optimal way of implementing this considering that I can't (for architecture reasons) change the flow layout of the program?

Answer (score 0):

With more details about your problem, we could help you more (e.g. can each element of the three vectors be computed in parallel? Does the number of entries in each vector change during the computation? Are the entries of different kind/variable type?...)

Yo can try the following:

Put all you local variable of function doLongOne as member variable in ClassOne, and all local variable of function doLongTwo as member variable in ClassTwo and the same with doLongThree

```
while(keepRunning())
{
  ClassOne one;
  ClassTwo two;
  ClassThree three;

  #pragma omp sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    { 
      one.prepare(); // do all the staff before the "great loop" in function doLongOne
    }
    #pragma omp section
    { 
      two.prepare(); // do all the staff before the "great loop" in function doLongTwo
    }
    #pragma omp section
    { 
      three.prepare(); // do all the staff before the "great loop" in function doLongThree
    }
  }
  int index[4];
  index[0] = 0;
  index[1] = index[0] + one.get_loop_num();
  index[2] = index[1] + one.get_loop_num();
  index[3] = index[2] + one.get_loop_num();

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i=0; i<index[3]; i++)
  {
    int j=1;
    while (j<4 && i>index[j]) j++;
    if (j==4) {}// DO PANIC!
    switch (j)
    {
    case 1:
      one.doLong(i-index[j-1]); // call directly (*it).doLong();
      break;
    case 2:
      two.doLong(i-index[j-1]); // call directly (*it).doLong();
      break;
    case 3:
      three.doLong(i-index[j-1]); // call directly (*it).doLong();
      break;
    default:
      // DO PANIC !
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: The basic structure of the program is essentially: great loop calls its own functions. All of those functions call the name-matching function of the "current mode". That function in current mode loops through all of its children and calls THEIR name-matching functions. No data is actually be changed except for the internal bottom level objects (which are only controlled by one thread at a time).